# Unable to inject code to the browser from the content.js file

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension, console, console.log

I am trying to make a chrome extension and in the content.js file have written certain code (the codes contained in the content.js file have been pasted below).

When I run the extension it seems that the "links" don't capture any objects and the href has 0 elements.

But when I paste the entire code from content.js to the console of the web page, it works perfectly fine showing me all the desired links. The same had been demonstrated in the picture that has been posted.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUK1q.png [link to image]

(The images shows the fact that after I run my extension and check the console,
it shows that href is empty and but when I plate the code from the content.js file directly to the console,
it shows entirely different results.)

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

```js
// start of code  
// javascript code written in the content.js file

[The images shows the fact that after I run my extension and check the console, 
it shows that href is empty and but when I plate the code from the content.js file directly to the console, 
it shows entirely different results.][1]


console.log("chrome extension ready to go");
var className = 'VkhHKd e7EEH nQaZq'; 
var links = document.getElementsByClassName(className), hrefs=[];
//console.log(links);
for (var i = 0; i<links.length; i++)
{   
    hrefs.push(links[i].href);
}
console.log(hrefs);
console.log(links.length);

// end of code
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your content.js set up in your manifest.json (if you don't have a content.css, just omit that css line):

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "theurlyouwanttoinjectthecontentscripton" ],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "css": ["content.css"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes I do have it set up in my manifest.json file, in fact if you look closely the console.log does work in the content.js file, it's just that the var link doesn't capture anything neither does the href. But it works perfectly fine when I copy paste the code directly in the web console.